# Python: Increasing timeout value in EMR using yelps MRJOB

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce, mrjob

I am using the yelp MRjob for writing some of the mapreduce programs. I am running it on  EMR. My program has reducer code which takes a long time to execute. I am noticing that because of the default timeout period in EMR I am getting this error

```
Task attempt_201301171501_0001_r_000000_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds.Killing!
```

I want a way to increase the timeout of the EMR. I read the mrjobs official documentation about the same but I was not able to understand the procedure. Can someone suggest a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've dealt with a similar issue with EMR in the past, the property you are looking for `mapred.task.timeout` which corresponds to **the number of milliseconds before a task will be terminated if it neither reads an input, writes an output, nor updates its status string**.

With MRJob, you could add the following option:

```
--jobconf mapred.task.timeout=1800000
```

**EDIT**: It appears that some EMR AMIs appear do not support setting parameters like timeout with jobconf at run time. Instead, you must use Bootstrap-time configuration like this:

```
--bootstrap-action="s3://elasticmapreduce/bootstrap-actions/configure-hadoop -m mapred.task.timeout=1800000"
```

I would still try the first one to start with and see if you can get it to work, otherwise try the bootstrap action.

To run any of these parameters, just create your job extending from `MRJob`, this class has a `jobconf` method that will read your `--jobconf` parameters, so you should specify these as regular options on command line:

```
python job.py --num-ec2-instances 42 --python-archive t.tar.gz -r emr --jobconf mapred.task.timeout=1800000 /path/to/input.txt
```

Comment: Where should i write this??

Comment: @ravijimagna I added more details in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Charles ...but now I have this error Task attempt_201301180606_0001_r_000000_0 failed to report status for 1802 seconds. Killing!

Comment: @ravijimagna Well I guess you could keep increasing your timeout, it really depends on what your task does, 1800 seconds sounds quite a lot already, is it expected behavior?

Comment: Not at all. When I run my files locally it takes around 15 minutes to finish up the entire job. EMR is taking too much time and the code is exactly the same in both cases. Any solution in this regard?

Comment: BTW, I am not mentioning the --python archive in my input..is that the reason?